# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I have upgraded my Flutter project version to the current latest flutter version (2.5.3) after upgraded occurs this error.

Code as follows,

```
final List<Object> _prop = [];

@override
  List<Object> get prop => _prop;

  EnvironmentState([List prop = const []]) {
    this._prop.addAll(prop);         //        <------ Here is the error occurs
  }
```

Error as follows,

```
The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message tells us, `List<dynamic>` can't be assigned to `List<Object>`. In this case you provide parameter, default List is dynamic.

```dart
final List<Object> _prop = [];

  @override
  List<Object> get prop => _prop;

  EnvironmentState([List<Object> prop = const []]) {
    this._prop.addAll(prop);  
  }
```

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can find more about [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/List-class.html)